# Aggragate with reffered collection with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am writing microservice that could filter output by field in a refed Object or in the parent Object. For that, I think, I need to join with the referred object.

So my parent object looks like that

```
{
  _id: 6234cd54fa8bcb2604f625cf,
  createdBy: 6234cd53fa8bcb2604f625cc,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  dateStart: 2022-03-18T18:19:59.998Z,
}
```

And refed object with name User

```
{
          _id: 6234cd53fa8bcb2604f625cc,
          role: 'admin',
          firstName: 'Test',
          lastName: 'User',
}
```

For aggregate them I use this code:

```
 Model.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'User',
            localField: 'createdBy',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'admin',
          }
        },
        
      ])
.exec()
```

This returns me parent object with an empty array in Aggregated field admin [].

Screenshot of collection
[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your documents (where collection names are visible)? It could be you are entering incorrect collection name or  `createdBy` is stored as ObjectID and not a string?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, yep, createdBy is stored as objectId with ref: User